# How do I create a vbYesNo MsgBox outside of For Each loop?

Tags: excel, vba

**What I'm trying to do:**

If sheets exist that are NOT named "Macro" > prompt user with MsgBox > if yes, delete all sheets not named "Macro"

*But only show MsgBox **ONCE** (do not show MsgBox for each sheet if more than 1 sheet exists)*

**Problem with current code:**
Still getting MsgBox prompt when "Macro" is the only sheet that exists.

**Current code:**

```
Sub reset()
    
    Dim conditionMet As Boolean
    Dim answer      As Integer
    
    conditionMet = FALSE
    answer = MsgBox("There Is already data here. Click Yes To delete reset macro.", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = FALSE
    
    For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Sheet.Name <> "Macro" Then
            conditionMet = TRUE
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next Sheet
    
    If conditionMet Then
        If answer = vbYes Then
            Sheet.Delete
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = TRUE
    
End Sub
```

Comment: The only MsgBox you are creating is right at the top before you even look at what exists.  Or is there supposed to be a second one at the end?  If the one at the top is the one you are talking about and you want it to only display that MsgBox if conditionMet is True then stick it inside the `If conditionMet Then` statement that is after the loop.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach:

```vba
Const KEEP_THIS As String = "Macro"
Dim ws As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(KEEP_THIS)
On Error GoTo 0
If ws Is Nothing Or ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count = 1 Then Exit Sub 'no "Macro" sheet

If MsgBox("Delete all data sheets?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
'remove all non-Macro sheets
For i = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count To 1 Step -1
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
        If .Name <> KEEP_THIS Then .Delete
    End With
Next i
```

Answer (score 2):

### Delete All Sheets Except a Specified One

- The following shows how to avoid a few (less) common surprises.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub resetWorkbook()
    
    Const SheetName As String = "Macro"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' There has to be at least one sheet in the workbook.
    If wb.Sheets.Count = 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Check for existence.
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim sh As Object: Set sh = wb.Sheets(SheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If sh Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    If MsgBox("There Is already data here. Click Yes To delete reset macro.", _
        vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    
    ' An only sheet in a workbook has to be visible.
    If Not sh.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
        sh.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    End If
    
    ' Write the other sheet names to an array.
    Dim SheetNames() As String: ReDim SheetNames(1 To wb.Sheets.Count - 1)
    Dim n As Long
    For Each sh In wb.Sheets
        ' Allow case-insensitivity i.e. A = a.
        If StrComp(sh.Name, SheetName, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
            n = n + 1
            SheetNames(n) = sh.Name
        End If
    Next sh
    
    ' Delete sheets in one go with no pop-ups.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.Sheets(SheetNames).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Number of sheets deleted: " & n, vbInformation, "Success"
    
End Sub
```